# Order of $x$ in $\mathbb F_q[x]/(g(x))$

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb F_q$ be a finite field and $g(x)$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb F_q[x]$ with non zero constant term. Given the factorization of $g(x)=p_1(x)^{e_1}\dots p_k(x)^{e_k}$, give an estimate for the order of $x$ in $(\mathbb F_q[x]/(g(x)))^\times$.

Using Chinese Remainder Theorem and basic properties of the order and lcm, one gets that the order of $x$ divides 
$$
C(g)=q^d(q-1) \cdot \operatorname{lcm}(\{(q^{\deg p_i}-1)/(q-1)\}_{i\in \{1\dots k\}}),
$$
where $d$ is the smallest integer such that $q^d$ is larger than any of the $e_i$'s. But I am not really able to nicely estimate this quantity...

Comment: Thanks. If $g(x)$ has a non zero constant term, $x$ is invertible, so it has an order (in the group of the invertible elements of the ring, obviously).

Comment: AFAICT this is pretty much what you can say about the order. The simple estimate is to replace lcm with product, but that's about it, I think.

Comment: Ok, this is reassuring, thanks!